# Best succinct wording for app field

Tags: user-research

I am just making a little app and it collects team data. One of my fields is "number of players". In this sense I mean how many players are playing on the pitch at any given time. But it could certainly be construed as how many players are in your roster. So i'm a little stuck as to a better way to word this? Any ideas would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More context around your app and needs would certainly help better provide a solution, but **how about simply labeling the field "Players on Pitch"**?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could solve this with some data organization. **Provide context to the data you're collecting.**

Group data related to the pitch together, and group data related to the roster together.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6kJmR.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Number of **active players** or number of **starters** would work.

Answer (score 1):

You could set it as a question that the user will answer.

- How many on you roster?
- How many on the pitch?

May seem verbose, but clearer.